# How do I make my banner in tumblr link to another site?

Tags: html, tumblr

I'm trying to make the banner in my tumblr blog link to another site. I can't figure out how to do it. The following is the code I found in the custom html tab but I can't seem to make my banner clickable. Where exactly should I add the website address for the link? Any help will be appreciated.

```
<div id="page" class="{block:IfLeftSidebar}left-sidebar{/block:IfLeftSidebar}{block:IfNotLeftSidebar}right-sidebar{/block:IfNotLeftSidebar}">
    {block:IfBannerImage}
    <div class="banner">
        <a href="/"title="{Title}"><img id="banner" src="{image:Banner}" alt="banner"/></a>
    </div>
    {block:IfBannerImage}
    {block:IfNotBannerImage}
    {block:IfBlogTitleInPageHeader}
    <div class="banner textual">
        <h1 class="blog-title"><a href="/">{Title}</a></h1>
        {block:IfTagline}<p class="tagline">{text:Tagline}</p>{/block:IfTagline}
    </div>
    {/block:IfBlogTitleInPageHeader}
    {/block:IfNotBannerImage}
    <div id="content">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="banner">
    <a href="/"title="{Title}"><img id="banner" src="{image:Banner}" alt="banner"/></a>
</div>
```

put your website in the

```
href=""
```