# How to make a Tumblr Banner link to a site?

Tags: html, tumblr, banner

I know that this question has already been asked, but the HTML I am looking at has been written in a strange format, in my opinion. I already looked at this thread: [How do I make my banner in tumblr link to another site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545154/how-do-i-make-my-banner-in-tumblr-link-to-another-site), but it wasn't helpful, as that "a href" bit is just missing.

```
<div class="header">

{block:IfHeaderImage}<img style="{block:IndexPage}width:520px;{block:IndexPage} {block:PermalinkPage}width:500px;{/block:PermalinkPage} overflow:hidden; float:left; padding-bottom:15px;" src="{image:header}" {/block:IfHeaderImage}

<div class="blogtitle"{Title}</div>

<div style="text-align:right;">

</div></div>

<div style="padding-top:15px;"><div id="content">
```

Since it's missing that "a href" part, I don't know where to put the link. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Here:, change # to which link.

```
<a href="#">
<div class="header">

{block:IfHeaderImage}<img style="{block:IndexPage}width:520px;{block:IndexPage} {block:PermalinkPage}width:500px;{/block:PermalinkPage} overflow:hidden; float:left; padding-bottom:15px;" src="{image:header}" {/block:IfHeaderImage}

<div class="blogtitle"{Title}</div>

<div style="text-align:right;">

</div></div>
</a>

<div style="padding-top:15px;"><div id="content">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="blogtitle"><a href="yournontumblr.url">{Title}</a></div>
```

Put the link there, inside the divs.

{word} <- This notation is used on tumblr to call up various page elements that are user defined. It's based on PHP, if I'm not mistaken. {Title} is something that you define in the content management system/dashboard.

Hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming in the tumblr Customize menu, you have a header image uploaded to *header* and the option *IfHeaderImage* checked in the Tumblr Customize menu:

```
{block:IfHeaderImage}<a href="INSERTURLHERE"><img style="{block:IndexPage}width:520px;{block:IndexPage} {block:PermalinkPage}width:500px;{/block:PermalinkPage} overflow:hidden; float:left; padding-bottom:15px;" src="{image:header}" /></a>{/block:IfHeaderImage}
```

The link tags `<a href ... >` wrap around the `img` tag, rendering that image a link. Change the INSERTURLHERE to the URL of the site you wish to link to.

Otherwise, if you decide not to have a header image, gersande's method works.