# TUMBLR : How to modify the html code to put links url on these elements?

Tags: html, tumblr

I just want to do that on my Tumblr :

[Tumblr screenshot with what i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmOsn.jpg)

I found some answers on this forum ([How to make a Tumblr Banner link to a site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509265/how-to-make-a-tumblr-banner-link-to-a-site) and [How do I make my banner in tumblr link to another site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545154/how-do-i-make-my-banner-in-tumblr-link-to-another-site)) But i really don't know where to write to codes given as answers in the basic html code of my Tumblr.

Does someone know it ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi. As a new user here I strongly suggest visiting the [help] as your two questions do not meet the quality standard for this website. If all of your participation fails to meet this site's standards you will find yourself unable to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0):

you should  put each one image tag in `<a>` tag with custom URL

```
<a href="http://yourlink.com/"> <img src="htttp://your_image_address.com/"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can search on the google and find the answer. but for link one text to another page you can use

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a>
```

for more information about link check [this website](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp)

Comment: Actually i found some answers on this forum (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509265/how-to-make-a-tumblr-banner-link-to-a-site and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545154/how-do-i-make-my-banner-in-tumblr-link-to-another-site) but i don't know where to write the code given as answers in the basic code of my Tumblr blog.

Comment: <a href="your destination link">My Blog</a>